# Fixed-Size Bit-Array in D

Tags: d, bitarray, compile-time-constant, bitvector

If I want a compile-time-sized bit-array (on stack) what are my alternatives?

I'm thinking something like

```
struct Bitset(size_t nBits) {
    enum wsz = 8 * size_t.sizeof; // Word-Size.
    enum nBlocks = nBits/wsz + nBits % wsz * wsz;
    alias _bits this;
    size_t[nBlocks] _bits;
}
```

along with `bt` and alikes from `core.bitop`

would suit my needs.

Has anybody already written a template for this along with some nice boolean operations?

Comment: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html might have what you need edit: i don't think it goes on the stack though...

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind though is  copy/pasting the bitmanip struct (if it otherwise looks like what you need) and replace the dynamic array backing pieces with a static array. Shouldn't be too big of a modification, though I haven't actually tried yet.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: I did just that. It took me about half an hour to convert BitArray to statically sized BitSet and make the unitttests pass.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: One question. Why does `BitArray` contain only `init` members but no constructors?

Comment: Looks like this is a port of the D1 std.bitarray that hasn't been fully updated (it still uses old style operator overloading too). D1 didn't have struct constructors, so you had to use an init method. (yes, definitely a port, see my answer to your other question which has a link to the old docs+source too)

Comment: +1 for the question. BitArray is just too old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply check if [BitArray](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html#.BitArray) uses the stack or not. If not, grab the source code and modify it...

IMHO BitArray could be improved with some sort of option whether you want it on the stack or not...

Comment: Yeah, agree. This is what D is made for...adaptivity :)